# Installing SVN without root access

Tags: linux, svn

I have a remote SSH access to a web server. It's running on CentOS and I was wondering how can I install a SVN client locally ?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Most unix programs can be compiled, installed, and run without root permissions.  With tools that use autoconf, you just need to specify a prefix as to where to install the resulting artifacts.  The procedure usually looks like this:

```
./configure --prefix=${HOME}
make
make check
make install
```

With subversion, you may have to compile a number of dependencies first.  These include:

- libapr and libapr-util
- SQLite
- libz
- libneon or libserf (optional)
- OpenSSL (optional)
- Berkely DB (optional)
- libsasl (optional)
- KDELibs, GNOME Keyring (optional)

Answer (score 2):

You could download the [SVN source code](http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#source-release). At the beginning, you can say `./configure --prefix=/path/to/home/directory`. Then you can `make`, and `make install`, and subversion will be installed to the path specified in "prefix". This would install it in a place where your user could run the program, but it wouldn't be installed system-wide.

Comment: Or even just `--prefix=$HOME`, since that should be set properly.

Answer (score 1):

Download latest sources from http://subversion.tigris.org

unpack it, and change dir to result folder (for example subversion-1.8.1 - latest one)

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME 

make install
```

check for result

```
$HOME/bin/svn --version
```

enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

Download SVN source to your home directory and run make without installing. SVN executable should appear in src directory or similar.

Another way would be to find appropriate SVN rpm package and [extract](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html) contents instead of installing.